# icefaces visible="#{graphicDataController.drawingItems.size() > 0 }" to CSS style attribute

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Because, Primefaces does not have a visible attribute as Icefaces has. 
So, I migrated  the visible="false" to style="display: none" and `visible="true"` to `style="display: inline"` as a Primefaces attribute.

However, I have to migrate also `visible="#{graphicDataController.drawingItems.size() > 0 }"` or something like this `visible="#{workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable() }"`

I want to use something like this `style="display: #{bean.prop ? 'inline' : 'none'}"` but instead of `bean.prop`, I have this complex expression `workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable()`.

I do not know how to evaluate this complex expression `workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable()` inside of CSS.

**SOLVED**
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

Comment: I want to use this style="display: #{bean.prop ? 'inline' : 'none'}" attribute in CSS but instead of bean.prop I have a complex expression something like "workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable()"

Comment: But I have to evaluate whole expression e.g. "workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable()" with or too. It returns boolean.

Comment: Ah, you can just use "and" or "or". Just as you have written it. As far as I know

Comment: Can I use two display in style CSS? 
Somethig like this style="display: #{workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() ? 'inline' : 'none'}; display: #{workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable() ? 'inline' : 'none'}

Comment: Yes I would say, but I can't see it is meaningful in your example? All operators are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html

Comment: Also depending on situation it could be better to do style="#{workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() ? 'display: inline' : ''}; (for example). Then 'display' would be inherited if false

Comment: I see that I can use these logical operators: and, &&, or, ||, not, !
So, can I use #{workbasketBean.isCurrenTaskAvailable() or workbasketBean.currentProcessAvailable() ? 'inline' : 'none'}" , please?

Comment: Thanks, works great. Please, give this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either `or` or `||` in Expression Language, for example

```
style="display: #{bean.isBool1() or bean.isBool2() ? 'inline' : 'none'}".
```

Here's an overview of EL operators for [Java EE 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaik.html) and [Java EE 7](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-el005.htm#BNAIK).